# Creating a go binary as debian binary package for a custom repository

Tags: go, binary, package, debian

I am trying to package a binary written in `Go` as a debian/ubuntu binary package. This would be available for download from a custom web server and `apt key`.

I am - very - confused.

I looked at https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging first. This looks like exhaustive, without wanting to say too complex.

What confuses me is that the file `debian/rules` contains a `make` command. But we don't have a `Makefile`, do I need to create one?

In fact I am at the `debuild -us -uc` step, and it obviously failed.

Then I saw this: https://askubuntu.com/a/251892 , where it says:

> Avoid the Debian bureaucracy by just building the binary:
>   dpkg-buildpackage -b

I did that, and the command completed, but looking at the generated package there it doesn't contain any binaries, only a `changelog.gz` and a `copyright` file in the app folder below `/usr/share/doc`.

So I am lost, I have no idea which tutorial to follow here to build a binary custom package, which, btw, later will be available for download signed. Obviously it is my first debian/ubuntu package I am creating.

Comment: This https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.en.html#simplemake seems to suggest that indeed there should be a `Makefile`

Comment: That's for source distributions. Binary distributions do not need a makefile.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/BinaryPackage?action=show&redirect=DebianPackage

Comment: Thanks, I had found that one, but that is only saying what a binary package is - not how to create one. There is this: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/, but it says: "The intended use of such a newly created archive is to install it only on your own box, not to get them into the official Debian distribution. " I don't want to get them into the official Debian distro, nor I want it to install just on my own box. I want people to reliably download and install it from our own repo....

Comment: Then you're fine. Being an **open-source** repository, Debian will not add packages to their repo without the source. In your own repo, you set your own rules.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a project written in go that is distributed as a .deb package in a repository.

I have to tell you that it is not easy to find documentation about it. I use [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) for that activity.

First create in a folder that represents your project on the destination computer. For example "/tmp/proj"

Inside that folder you must put everything you want to distribute in the package. For example, if your compiled binary is called "myapp" and you want to put it in "/usr/bin/", then you have to create the folder "/tmp/proj/usr/bin" and put in it the executable file with the permissions you will use.

This way with all the files you want to distribute.

Then create a script that you will use to generate the package:

```
PKG_NAME= application name, one word, lowercase
PKG_DESCRIPTION= Brief description of the package
PKG_VERSION= Version, in x.y.z format
PKG_RELEASE= Correlative number from 1 onwards
PKG_MAINTAINER= Your name and email. Format: "name" < email >
PKG_VENDOR= Your company name
PKG_URL= URL of your product

FPM_OPTS="-n $PKG_NAME -v $PKG_VERSION --iteration $PKG_RELEASE"

fpm -s dir -t deb ${FPM_OPTS} -f \
    -maintainer "$PKG_MAINTAINER" \
    --vendor "$PKG_VENDOR" \
    --url "$PKG_URL" \
    --description "$PKG_DESCRIPTION" \
    --architecture "amd64" \
    -C /tmp/proj \
    .
```

And that's it! 
Well, there's a lot to learn.

Comment: Thank you! I am going through the same, the docs are there but confusing so it's a bag of learning indeed! I came to similar conclusions, however I did not know `fpm`, so I'll check that out.